# How to compare datetime objects in single column of excel sheet using openpyxl?

Tags: python, date, datetime, openpyxl, python-datetime

I am attempting to create a python script to iterate over all the rows of a specific column in an excel spredsheet. This column contains dates, I need to compare each of these dates in order to find and return the oldest date in the excel sheet. After which, I will need to modify the data in that row.

I have tried to append the dates into a numpy array as datetime objects, this was working but I cannot traverse through the array and compare the dates. I have also tried to reformat the dates in the excel sheet to datetime objects in python and then compare but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

I have tried some other unsuccessful methods. These are the ones where I got closest to achieving what I want. I'm quite lost, please help!

```py
import openpyxl
import numpy as np
import datetime

def main():

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Python Telecom Project.xlsx")
    sheet = wb.active


def menuSelection():

    while True:
        menuChoice = input("Please select one of the following options:\n1. Add User\n2.Delete User\n3.Modify User\n")

        if menuChoice not in ('1', '2', '3'):
            print("The input entered is invalid, please try again")
            continue
        else:
            break

    return menuChoice

def findOldestDate():

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Python Telecom Project.xlsx")
    sheet = wb.active
##    startMult = np.empty((0,1000), dtype='datetime64[D]')
##    value = datetime.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    for rowNum in range(2, sheet.max_row+1):
        status = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=5).value
        d8 = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=6).value
        d8_2 = sheet.cell(row=rowNum+1, column=6).value
        d8.value = datetime.date.strftime(d8, "%Y-%m-%d")
        d8_2.value = datetime.date.strftime(d8_2, "%Y-%m-%d")
        d8.number_format = 'YYYY MM DD'
        d8_2.number_format = 'YYYY MM DD'

        if d8 < d8_2:
            oldestDate = d8
        elif d8 > d8_2:
            oldestDate = d8_2
        else:
            continue

    return oldestDate

##            array.append(startMult, date)
##
##    while counter < len(array)-1:
##
##        if array[counter] < array[counter + 1]:
##
##            oldestDate = array[counter]
##            counter += 1
##                
##        elif array[counter] > array[counter + 1]:
##
##            oldestDate = array[counter + 1]
##            counter += 1
##
##        else:
##            oldestDate = array[counter]
##            continue
##
##    return oldestDate


def addUser():

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Python Telecom Project.xlsx")
    sheet = wb.active

    dateTimeObj = datetime.date.today()

    print("Please enter the following information:\n")
    inputName = input("Name: ")
    inputNTID = input("NTID: ")
    inputRATSID = input("RATSID: ")
    inputStatus = input("Status: ")
    inputTaskNum = input("Task #: ")

    for rowVal in range(2, sheet.max_row+1):

        oldestDate = findOldDate()

        phoneNum = sheet.cell(row=rowVal, column=1).value
        name = sheet.cell(row=rowVal, column=2).value
        ntID = sheet.cell(row=rowVal, column=3).value
        ratsID = sheet.cell(row=rowVal, column=4).value
        status = sheet.cell(row=rowVal, column=5).value
        date = sheet.cell(row=rowVal, column=6).value

        if date == oldestDate:

            name = inputName
            ntID = inputNTID
            ratsID = inputRATSID
            status = inputStatus
            date = dateTimeObj

            print("\nChanges have been implemented successfully!")





##def deleteUser():
##    
##
##
##def modifyUser():




addUser()
```

This is the current error message:

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Prior to this one, I was getting:

```
can't compare 'str' to 'datetime'
```

What I want is the oldest date in the column to be returned from this function.

Comment: Have you imported datetime?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the entirety of your code--where do you import `datetime`, and do you alias it in some way that makes `datetime.datetime.strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` break?

Comment: This is not the only function but it is the only one where I am getting an error, I have tested the others and they seem to be working fine. I have added the import statements in the code above as it is in my script.

Comment: you `from datetime import *` which removes the need for the first `datetime.` because all of `datetime`'s associated modules and classes are in the namespace. So correct usage is just `datetime.strftime(...)` look to https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#available-types

Comment: Ahh I see, I have made a few changes, now it is just 'import datetime' and I am using 'value = datetime.date.strftime(...)' as there isn't actually a specific time value but am getting the following error:                                              
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'

Comment: @GiovaLomba The overall goal is to be able to modify rows of the excel sheet based on the oldest date found, as this is the row will need values to be changed. The functions above are not yet complete but I thought this would give a better idea. You should also be able to delete and add rows but I will deal with this later, once I figure out the current step these will be simpler.

Comment: @RaghavTaneja ok I understand. Below the easiest solution to the issue I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding the oldest date can be achieved with a one-liner like the following:

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt
from re import match

def oldest(sheet, column):
   """
   Returns the tuple (index, timestamp) of the oldest date in the given sheet at the given column.
   """
   return min([(i, dt.strptime(sheet.cell(row=i, column=column).value, '%Y %m %d').timestamp()) for i in range(2, sheet.max_row+1) if isinstance(sheet.cell(row=i, column=column).value, str) and  match(r'\d{4}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}', sheet.cell(row=i, column=column).value)], key=lambda x:x[1])
```

The longer, slower but more readable version follow:

```
def oldest(sheet, column):
   """
   Returns the tuple (index, timestamp) of the oldest date in the given sheet at the given column.
   """
   format = '%Y %m %d'
   values = list()
   for i in range(2, sheet.max_row+1):
      if isinstance(sheet.cell(row=i, column=column).value, str) and  match(r'\d{4}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}', sheet.cell(row=i, column=column).value):
         values.append((i, dt.strptime(sheet.cell(row=i, column=column).value, format).timestamp()))
   return min(values, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

If you need that, you can convert the retrieved timestamp back in the date format you had as shown in this sample session at the python REPL:

```py
>>> row, timestamp = oldest(sheet, 1)
>>> date = dt.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp[1]).strftime('%Y %m %d')
>>> date
'2019 10 31'
>>> row
30
```

Comment: I created a new python file because the other one was getting kind of messy. I've tried to implement this in there, when I run the code I get the following error:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py", line 172, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object                                                       The error is identified on the if statement below the for loop. Trying to look for a solution right now, but thank you for the answer! I think it should work with a few minor alterations.

Comment: That error came out because you probably have empty columns or having values that are not translated by `openpyxl` into strings. You should check your data or add a condition into the `if` statement in logic `and` with the previous one to check the type of the data into the cell. A suitable condition could be `isinstance(sheet.cell(i, column).value, str)`.